# where in a COLLADA .dae file is the information I would require to scale a 3d model for opengl?

Tags: opengl, scale, vertices

The vertices and normals for the object are all stored as floats inside the COLLADA file I can export from google sketchup. I wish to obtain the information to tell me how much each unit for the float would be in meters but can't seem to find it. I see that there is a matrix inside the COLLADA file I included bellow and the 1.968504 value looks suspicious judging by the range of vertices values inside the file and the measurements used inside the sketchup application drawing the model, but It appears to be a translation because apparently COLLAD uses row-major format so the 1.968504 is the x translation . I also noticed there is an element called unit in the xml which may be related but I can't figure out what to use :/?

Ideally I need to know the constant that relates a meter to a unit for the floats in each dimension and I need to scale all the values, which I could probably work out how to do if I understood what information from the file I need :/?

This is the matrix xml element:

```
<node id="ID2" name="instance_0">
        <matrix>1 0 0 1.968504 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
        <instance_node url="#ID3" />
</node>
```

This is the unit xml element:

```
   <unit meter="0.0254" name="inch" />
```

Comment: i wish to scale the object so it fits in the -1 to 1 range opengl uses and store the information telling me the constant that relates the floats to the actual dimensions in meters

Answer (score 0):

Those 16 numbers are a 4x4 matrix that combines information about translation, rotation and scale. If `m` if the matrix, then the scale vector is, using GLM as notation:

```cpp
glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(glm::length(glm::vec3(m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2])),
                            glm::length(glm::vec3(m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][2])),
                            glm::length(glm::vec3(m[2][0], m[2][1], m[2][2])));
```

This is a 3-component vector because scaling can be different in every axis.